# How do I return multiple values from render function in Datatables?

Tags: javascript, datatables

My knowledge in Javascript is quite poor and my question may appear a bit stupid. Anyway, here we go:
I have a column in Data-tables that fetches URLs from a MySQL database.The URLs points to images stored elsewhere. I use render function to do the job(see code below) as I can´t target the integer of the column(as it differs due to being situated in a hidden responsive child row)). That works fine.
Now I also want to add my own CSS to the image in the row.

How can I add this to my js below?

```
{ "data": "img",
  className: "min-phone",
  "render": function ( data, type, row) {
                return '<img src="http://beginning.of.url.to.image' + data + '" />';
           }
 }
```

Comment: You can use inlined styles like  `<img src="http://beginning.of.url.to.image' + data + ' style='width="100px";height="200px"' />`. or you can add your own css class and then use it in your css file to style it

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't seem to have any effect. I can´t use inline styles anyway as I need to target certain breakpoints in an external css file(in another words make the image smaller when showing on smaller devices).

Comment: Well, then based on the device you can add css class `return '<img src="http://beginning.of.url.to.image' + data + '" class="medium-screen" />';`
or `return '<img src="http://beginning.of.url.to.image' + data + '" class="large-screen" />';` and use these class in css file. Would that work?

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did the trick. In the end I used only one class in the js and pointed to an external style sheet with different media queries. Thanks again Siva.You made my day!

Comment: Glad that it worked :) . I have posted the same as an answer. Could you please accept it if it is fine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css class to get around this problem.

Based on the device you can add css class like below.

`return '<img src="http://beginning.of.url.to.image' + data + '" class="medium-screen" />';`

or

`return '<img src="http://beginning.of.url.to.image' + data + '" class="large-screen" />';`